# Unable to mount old PC HardDrive using CommandLines

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I know there are others subjects related but I assure you I went through a lot without finding an answer. It might well be because of my awfully basic knowledge in the domain.

**Context:**

I had an old ASUS G550J Republic of Gamers that broke down some years ago and I now want to get back my data (musics and images mainly).

**What I did for now:**

When I connected the hard drive I extracted, using an appropriate adapter, on my PC running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, GNOME Version => 3.36.2 there was a signal that the drive was acknowledged but no way to access it as a noob like me would have like to.

As I know my way (a little) on CommandLines I tried to access it this way. And after some research understood that the way here was to mount one of my HD partition to potentially access the data on it.

I installed drivers for `nfts` and `exfat` and tried to mount a partition.

**My unsatisfying results:**

Command: `sudo fdisk -l`

Output :

```
[...]
Disk /dev/sdb: 931,53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 244190646 sectors
Disk model: 014-1EJ164      
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x50ef685f

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *          2048     718847     716800  2,8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2           718848 1951678440 1950959593  7,3T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3       1951678464 1953521663    1843200    7G 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
```

This is my hard drive, and I tried to mount `/dev/sdb2`.

```
sudo mount -t vfat -o iocharset=utf8,umask=000 /dev/sdb2 /media/usb

mount: /media/usb: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

```
sudo mount -t ntfs -o nls=utf8,umask=0222 /dev/sdb2 /media/usb

NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb2': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdb2' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

```
sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sdb2 /media/exfat
FUSE exfat 1.3.0
ERROR: exFAT file system is not found.
```

I know it would be better to know the fs to reduce the possibilities here but I do not know how to do that.

Does anyone can tell me:

- If what I want to do is possible,
- Where I am missing a step or some important information I am unable to understand ?

Thanks a lot in advance, I hope I was clear in my explanations.

**Benoit**

Comment: What is the file system type on the drive? You proved it is not NFS or exfat OR that it is simply a bad drive.

Comment: Hi David, do you know how to determine if it's a bad drive, or the specific filesystem ? 
That's one of the things I'm trying to do but I won't find a clear way to say "OK it's bad, lets give up"+

Comment: What OS was the machine you removed it from? If it was windows try putting the drive in another windows machine and see if it is recognized. I very much doubt a solution from 2017 will help.

Comment: It was Windows indeed, Windows 8 I think.
I tried, it's recognized but the only option is to format it.

Comment: So not really recognized if it cant tell what file system type is on it. Looks like what ever was on it is most likely lost.